# Why do I keep getting an I/O exception?

Tags: java, exception, io

I had created code to access the file I downloaded, but that is not what the assignment wants. It wants me to access the information using the URL given here. I'm not sure why I keep getting IO Exception.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    int test = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    try{
    java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL("http://cs.armstrong.edu/liang/data/Scores.txt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(url.openStream());
    while (input.hasNext()){
        int score = input.nextInt();
        sum += score;
        i++;
    }
    }
    catch(java.net.MalformedURLException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(java.io.IOException ex){
    System.out.println("I/O Errors: no such file");
    }


    int avg = sum / i;
    System.out.println("The average is: " + avg);
    System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);




}
```

STACKTRACE

```
java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
at readfile.main(readfile.java:15)
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at readfile.main(readfile.java:30)

Comment: Are you able to hit the URL from browser?

Comment: Can you print the stacktrace for that exception?

Comment: I am able to hit the URL from the browser.

Comment: I printed Stack trace for it and got this. 

java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument: connect

Comment: @user2198019: are you behind any proxy? Then you need to set the proxy in java code before connecting to the URL

Comment: you should not catch an io exception and print that it was for "file not found" without checking what it was actually for.

Comment: Can you print the stacktrace in your question?

Comment: @Anubhab Yes i can print stacktrace.

Comment: @Anubhab When i print stacktrace it says I get a socket exception.

Comment: OMG...What we all are trying to say is just copy paste the stacktrace here in Stackoverflow.com. !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Anubhab: I kept trying to put it in the comment but it was too long. I have placed it in with my question, as I just found the edit button. I am new here, sorry about the confusion.

Comment: You should not add any code/ stacktrace in comment..you have to put them along with your question.. :)

Comment: Are you behind any proxy??Do you use any proxy to get internet connection?

Comment: @Anubhab: No I do not, the only security I have is what win7 comes with and Norton, and I have disabled both firewalls.

Comment: I tried running your code and it worked fine for me. Most likely you need to set proxy setting.

Comment: @Anubhab: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed so I can turn it in for my grade.

Comment: @user2198019 If my answer has helped you then you can upvote it or accept it if it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is exactly fine. Just add the below section to set proxy details before connecting.

```
//The follwing settings is needed for Connecting to internet from Local Network
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "ip.add.of.proxy");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "80");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyUser", "user_name"); // Your username
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPassword", "*************"); // your password
```

And also move the below code inside the **try catch** block otherwise if connection fails you will get `divide by zero` exception.

```
int avg = sum / i;
System.out.println("The average is: " + avg);
System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
```